# how can return value with require file in node js?

Tags: node.js, require

I am new to node.js , and use ari client.
I have two .js files that first one is required in second one. I have declared a variable in second one that must contain return value of first file but console.log(variable) is undefined although in first file return value is not null.

in first file :

```
var db = require("./database.js");
var service_info = db.select(connection,'select * from services where ivr_shortcode = ?',service);
console.log(service_info);
```

service_info is undefined;

in second file :

```
this.select = function (connection,query,data){
connection.query(query,[data],function(err, results){
    if(err)
    {
        throw err;
    }
    else
    {
        return results;
    }
});}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just return values from callback due to call being asynchronous, you should use another function to get the results:

```
// file 'database.js'
exports.select = function (connection, query, data, callback) {
    connection.query(query, [data], callback);
}
```

Than in your main:

```
// I assume `connection` and `service` are defined somewhere before (like in your original code)
var db = require("./database.js");
var service_info = db.select(connection,'select * from services where ivr_shortcode = ?',service, function(err, service_info){
  console.log(service_info);
});
```

P.S.
You should really read some docs and look into [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) to get better understanding of scope visibility and closures

Answer (score 0):

To deal with such condition you needs to implement it using the async/await.

```
exports.select = async function (connection,query,data){
await connection.query(query,[data],function(err, results){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else{
        return 
    }
  });
}
```

This will waits until you get the result. So undefined condition never arise.

Answer (score -1):

you have to export select.
something like this :

```
exports.select = function (connection,query,data){
connection.query(query,[data],function(err, results){
    if(err)
    {
        throw err;
    }
    else
    {
        return 
    }
});}
```

Comment: I think your problem is with your select function. what are you returning from that?

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani, FYI using this.functionName do define functions in modules is totally ok, this is not an issue for OP.